# How to install wine on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: wine

I am a windows user, and I don't know nothing about Ubuntu and how does it works. I don't know how to access my computer, I don't know how to access command prompt nothing.

Just now I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, due to wifi problem I reinstalled Ubuntu and now the wifi is working fine.

Now I am not able to install any of the exe file. I am trying to install file zilla,internet download manager, 7zip, and as a blogger I would like to install some other blogging related tools which install on Adobe Air.

Can any one please help me and instruct me in detail step by step on how to install wine on Ubuntu 14.04.

Or are there any other programs which makes to install windows related applications.

Comment: You can actually install all those from the software center, or from command line. You don't often need wine - there is normally an alternative.

Answer (score 4):

Windows programs can not be run in Linux directly, both systems are too different.
Linux has a ton of applications, FileZilla and 7zip for example are available as native Linux programs ready to install and use.

If you want to use windows programs on Linux than you need to install a runtime environment like Wine. Installation instructions can be found [here](https://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu) (WineHQ).

Please note that you still need to have a license for all applications you use in wine.

Comment: Also, a lot of FileZilla's basic functionality is covered by the Files program (Nautilus).

Comment: Yes I am trying to install windows programs on Ubuntu. Not only that I have many more programs to be installed. And with reference to the link provided I have downloaded and installed the wine program. Next what should I do, how Do I install programs.

Comment: Edited my answer, you can't just use windows programs on Linux.

Also please read the wine documentations.

Answer (score 4):

1. Read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal to learn how to start and use a terminal for the command prompt (implied question)
2. Once you have a terminal, type these two commands:

   sudo apt-get update

   sudo apt-get install wine

The first one refreshes the list of packages; the second does the actual installation.

This method will give you the Ubuntu version of Wine, which may not be quite as up to date as the version given by the method recommended in the previous answer by Jan.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, as You've been working with Windows, You have to understand that Ubuntu has totally different way of installing applications. Ok, maybe not so totally, but I will explain it later. Also applications are often different.

Here we mostly use repositories about which You can read here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_repository . It's generally the 'storage location' from which files are downloaded and automatically installed. They are also used to keep installed applications up to date.

Honestly for me this way is a lot of more comfortable then on Windows. Here You just need to type one command or open Ubuntu Software Center application (Synaptic in future maybe), find application You want, click 'install', type Your password and... that's all You have to do. What's more it also automatically check if there's newer version of application and kindly asks You about permission to update it.

When some application is not available in Your current set of repositories You just add new one to the list. Don't worry now - most of typical applications are in default repositories.

To be honest, while installing application from repository it just automatically downloads correct .deb file and installs it. That means that You can always manually download .deb file You want and install it.

Ok, now answering Your real question.
You can install Wine by opening 'Ubuntu Software Center' from Dash, finding this application, clicking install and typing Your password. That's only one way to deal with it, but I guess that the easiest one.

Anyway the thing is You probably do not really need Wine now. Just type 'filezilla', 'download manager' and anything alse You want in Ubuntu Software Center. There can be some problem with Adobe Air but I believe that if You search about it, You will find solution or alternative.

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: Synaptic in the *past*. It used to be installed by default and was removed. USC is the way forward.

Comment: True, but I meant that Synaptic is more complex than USC. I believe some users just don't use USC any more after some time, switching to Synaptic.